Have a query in singleton pattern in Head First Design Patterns book
public class ChocolateBoiler {
     private boolean empty;
     private boolean boiled;
     
     private ChocolateBoiler() {
     empty = true;
     boiled = false;
     }
     
     public void fill() {
     if (isEmpty()) {
     empty = false;
     boiled = false;
     // fill the boiler with a milk/chocolate mixture
     }
     }
     public void drain() {
     if (!isEmpty() && isBoiled()) {
     // drain the boiled milk and chocolate
     empty = true;
     }
     }
     public void boil() {
     if (!isEmpty() && !isBoiled()) {
     // bring the contents to a boil
     boiled = true;
     }
     }
     
     public boolean isEmpty() {
     return empty;
     }

     public boolean isBoiled() {
     return boiled;
     }
}

I was studying Design patterns - Head First book by Bert and Kathy Sierra . On Page no - 176, there is a brain power exercise.

Choc-O-Holic has done a decent job of ensuring bad things don’t happen, don’t you think? Then again, you probably suspect that if two ChocolateBoiler instances get loose, some very bad things can happen. How might things go wrong if more than one instance of ChocolateBoiler is created in an application?

I am not able to get what could go wrong. Can you please help. How 2 instances of this class can interfere. I am not able to understand.

I think the idea is that there is only one physical boiler, and if you end up with two copies in your code, then things like adding the wrong ingredients to the one boiler could happen.  Check the text for the problem description to see if I'm right that there is only one physical boiler.

If more than one instance is created you could see this scenario happening:
instance1 is created then:
instance1.empty == true;
instance1.boiled == false;

instance2 is created then:
instance2.empty == true;
instance2.boiled == false;

we call fill() method on instance1 then:
instance1.empty == false;
instance1.boiled == false;

we call fill() method on instance2 then the chocolate boiler will be filled with an additional load of chocolate.
if we have had only one instance it would have been impossible to fill the boiler a second time.
This is only one exemple of what could have happened.
I hope it will help you to understand the singleton pattern power.
